# Illustrator Rectangle Tool disabled

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to draw rectangles but found that the tool has been disabled.
I'm sure I subscribed to Illustrator but why so many tools are disabled?
They look grey here:
[image]

Comment: Its not disabled, it is just a indication that the tool is allready in the tool bar.  And there it is 4 item from the top.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my own problem... Right click the icons on the left panel and they will unfold... intuitive design...

[image]